# Revolution Sliders fonts are pixelated and don't look good in iPhone6 in responsive website

Tags: javascript, fonts, mobile-safari, revolution-slider

We are developing a responsive website with WordPress and introduced sliders with Revslider. But, as we have tested it with iPhone6+ using safari after loading in 2-3 slides font get pixelated and shows blur text title and description.

Can anyone suggest Slider setting / CSS patch to make font consistent in all the medium? Surprisingly, iPad and iPhone5 shows appropriate fonts in slider only iPhone6 has font pixelation issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have got a resolution of my question. Use this if anyone have a similar problem.

> .rev_slider_wrapper .tp-caption {
>       -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
>       -webkit-text-stroke:1px transparent;
>       -webkit-transform: none !important; }

By Applying above three lines of code in CSS, you will be able to resolve Font Pixelated which happened in my case.